# What is the best way to solve IE 10 cache issue from Angularjs project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api, browser-cache

We have Angularjs project where data is coming through service calls from ASP.NET Web API project. The pages work properly in Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers. But in IE there is an issue that data does not render properly, even though the data is being saved into database. It is displaying cached data in the UI instead of showing newly saved data.

Comment: Hope that Edge will do a better job ;) Usually problems like this can be solved by sending a timestamp with the request but I'm no angular expert sorry

Comment: Did you tried this --`$state.go('otherState', {cache: false})`

Comment: thanks tim-we, Sappy.. both solutions didn't work.